# C# MVC limited reader excel

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc

I need to read an excel file, search the id for each value and save those values in the database:
[Excel original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j9pw.png)

[table in SQL Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lmCW.png)

This is my code:

```
int rowCount = 51,colCount = 11;
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\melissa\Desktop\lista_items.xlsx");
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

for (int i = 2; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            item = xlRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2.ToString();
            id_color = consultas.buscar_color_codigo(xlRange.Cells[i, 2].Value2.ToString());
            id_fabricante = consultas.buscar_fabricante(xlRange.Cells[i, 3].Value2.ToString());
            id_size = consultas.buscar_talla(xlRange.Cells[i, 4].Value2.ToString());
            descripcion = xlRange.Cells[i, 5].Value2.ToString();
            id_body_type = consultas.buscar_body_type(xlRange.Cells[i, 6].Value2.ToString());
            id_gender = consultas.buscar_genero(xlRange.Cells[i,7].Value2.ToString());
            id_fabric_type = consultas.buscar_fabric_type(xlRange.Cells[i, 8].Value2.ToString());
            id_fabric_percent = consultas.buscar_percent(xlRange.Cells[i, 9].Value2.ToString());
            id_yarn = consultas.buscar_yarn(xlRange.Cells[i,10].Value2.ToString());
            division = xlRange.Cells[i, 11].Value2.ToString();}
```

To save in the database:

```
 Conexion con_s = new Conexion();
            SqlCommand com_s = new SqlCommand();
            com_s.Connection = con_s.AbrirConexion();
            com_s.CommandText = " INSERT INTO items(item,id_color,id_fabricante,id_size,descripcion,id_body_type,id_gender,id_fabric_type,id_fabric_percent,id_yarn,division)VALUES" +
                "('" + item + "','" + id_color + "','" + id_fabricante + "','" + id_size + "','" + descripcion + "','" + id_body_type +
                "','" + id_gender + "','" + id_fabric_type + "','" + id_fabric_percent + "','" + id_yarn + "','" + division + "'  ) ";
            com_s.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con_s.CerrarConexion();
```

It only search through and saves 10 rows, no more. it doesn't show any error, just stops . I already changed the httpRuntime executionTimeout and still nothing.

Any help will be appreciate

Comment: *Don't* use interop on a web server. You forget to close the application which means each request will leave an Excel instance behind. You can use ADO.NET and the Jet provider to read an Excel file, or a library like Epplus

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to construct SQL queries either. That's how SQL injection attacks happen. Image what would happen if someone wrote `'); Delete items;--` in the `division` field

Comment: Thanks, I'm using this only for a catalogue of items I need to put in the DB, I won't be permanent

Answer (score 0):

before uploading excel file, clear all the formats and comments etc. from editing tab of excel. It effects UsedRange property of excel.
Also it would be helpfull if you use this line of code to get last used cell and last used row.

```
int lastColumn = xlWorkSheet.LastColumnUsed().ColumnNumber();
int lastRow = xlWorkSheet.LastRowUsed().RowNumber();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Added those lines, both were 0 and still limited with rows